# Network-related or instance-specific error occurred : Specified file not found

Tags: c#, sql-server

I currently have a C# software (.Net Framework 4.8) that connects to a SQL Server HA Group.

This software is called by a WMS and can be called many times in a short timespan. (i.e. around 10 times within a 30 seconds window).

Each time the software run, it connects to the HA Group, do its queries and stops. But sometimes, specifically when there's a relatively high concurrent executions, we get the error « A Network-related or instance-specific error occurred while connecting to SQL Server. ».

The Inner Exception is « The specified file could not be found ».

Do you have any idea why do we get this error?

Thanks :)

I tried to add a `Thread.Sleep` and a new connection attempt when one error occurs, to delay the reconnection, but with no luck. Each time, I still get the error...

But retrying a few minutes later (with absolutely no change in the software itself) works as expected...

EDIT: As asked, here is the StackTrace of the error:

```
à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal&amp; connection)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal&amp; connection)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&amp; connection)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   à ExportTeliae.Program.Main(String[] args) dans C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\App\Program.cs:ligne 60
```

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75457933/edit) your question to include the full exception message including the stack trace - as text. Sometimes the stack trace can be more informative than the error message itself.

Comment: Do you specify [MultiSubnetFailover=true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sqlclient-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery#connecting-with-multisubnetfailover) in the connection string? That could cause these symptoms depending on the HA configuration.

Comment: I will try the `MultiSubnetFailover=True` option, as suggested by @DanGuzman.
Also, I added more traces to get the StackTrace and will update my post accordingly

Comment: Okay, so adding `MultiSubnetFailover=True` didn't work as expected @DanGuzman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update :

I also asked on the Microsoft Technet, and the issue came from our antivirus.

We added an exception, and since it has been made, we no longer have issues.

So my code was fine :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).